# Assigning a link to an image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a technique using third party software to create an interactive `Web APP` from a `PDF`.

It is possible to add `hotspots links` in the `PDF` which translate to the `Flash SWF desktop version app`?

There is also a mobile version which generates separate images and loses any links. By referencing some javascript it generates this html which I cant change directly.

My gol it to make for example `/files/mobile/2.jpg` and `/files/mobile/8.jpg` to link to some addresses chosen by me.

As I have no control to go into this `HTML`, could exists a way to add `javascript` to make certain images link based on their name?

```
<div id="fbBookPages" class="fbBookPages">
   <div class="fbPage" style="display: none; height: 1121px; width: 1121px; margin-left: 364px; z-index: 1;"><div class="fbPageLoading" style="display: none;"></div><img src="../files/mobile/1.jpg" style="width: 1121px; height: 1121px;"></div>
   <div class="fbPage" style="display: none; height: 1121px; width: 1121px; margin-left: 364px; z-index: 1;"><div class="fbPageLoading" style="display: none;"></div><img src="../files/mobile/2.jpg" style="width: 1121px; height: 1121px;"></div>
   <div class="fbPage" style="display: none; height: 1121px; width: 1121px; margin-left: 364px; z-index: 1;"><div class="fbPageLoading" style="display: none;"></div><img src="../files/mobile/3.jpg" style="width: 1121px; height: 1121px;"></div>
   <div class="fbPage" style="display: none; height: 1121px; width: 1121px; margin-left: 364px; z-index: 1;"><div class="fbPageLoading" style="display: none;"></div><img src="../files/mobile/4.jpg" style="width: 1121px; height: 1121px;"></div>
   <div class="fbPage" style="display: none; height: 1121px; width: 1121px; margin-left: 364px; z-index: 1;"><div class="fbPageLoading" style="display: none;"></div><img src="../files/mobile/5.jpg" style="width: 1121px; height: 1121px;"></div>
   <div class="fbPage" style="display: none; height: 1121px; width: 1121px; margin-left: 364px; z-index: 1;"><div class="fbPageLoading" style="display: none;"></div><img src="../files/mobile/6.jpg" style="width: 1121px; height: 1121px;"></div>
   <div class="fbPage" style="display: none; height: 1121px; width: 1121px; margin-left: 364px; z-index: 1;"><div class="fbPageLoading" style="display: none;"></div><img src="../files/mobile/7.jpg" style="width: 1121px; height: 1121px;"></div>
   <div class="fbPage" style="display: none; height: 1121px; width: 1121px; margin-left: 364px; z-index: 1;"><div class="fbPageLoading" style="display: none;"></div><img src="../files/mobile/8.jpg" style="width: 1121px; height: 1121px;"></div>
   <div class="fbPage" style="display: block; height: 1121px; width: 1121px; margin-left: 364px; z-index: 999;"><div class="fbPageLoading" style="display: none;"></div><img src="../files/mobile/9.jpg" style="width: 1121px; height: 1121px;"></div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's certainly possible, yes; but do you know in advance which `<img>` should link to which address? Should `../files/mobile/1.jpg` always link to `http://google.com` (as an example), or does that change based on some other context? Without further information it's very hard to supply a precisely relevant answer to this question.

Comment: Hi David, Thanks, yes I should have clarified.. 

../files/mobile/1.jpg always would link to http://google.com (or whatever)
but i would want ../files/mobile/8.jpg for example to link to a different address lets say http://www.thedesignbank.co.uk

The answer from mdziekon  works perfectly with one link but i would be looking to have multiple different link destinations and be able to set these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely do this in JavaScript, and you don't need any library:

```
function createImgLink(imgURL, linkURL) {
    // Select Image from DOM Tree
    var img = document.querySelector("[src='" + imgURL + "']");

    // Create a new Link (<a>) DOM Node
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = linkURL;

    // Insert newly created Link to the DOM Tree
    img.parentNode.insertBefore(link, img);

    // Move Image inside the Link
    link.appendChild(img);
}
```

Example:
to add "http://google.com" link to a "../files/mobile/1.jpg" image you would use the function like this:

```
createImgLink("../files/mobile/1.jpg", "http://google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery :

```
var url = ... // build your url here
var theNewLink = $('<a href="' + url + '"></a>'); // here you create a link from nowhere
var yourImageContainer = $(".fbPage") ... or something like that, depending on your context; // select one image container
var yourImage = yourImageContainer.find("img"); // select the image of this container
theNewLink.append(yourImage); // move the image into the new link
yourImageContainer.append(theNewLink); // add the new link to the container
```

Answer (score -1):

Using an Image as a Link
 To use an image as a link, simply nest the `<img>` tag inside the `<a>` tag:

```
An image as a link: <a href="http://www.yourlink.se">
<img border="0" alt="text" src="logo.gif" width="100" height="100">
</a>
```

Comment: "As I have no control to go into this HTML, could exists a way to add javascript to make certain images link based on their name?"